# Why are my fields initialized to null or to the default value of zero when I've declared and initialized them in my class' constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, field

<sub>This is meant to be a canonical question and answer for similar questions where the issue is a result of *shadowing*.</sub>

---

I've defined two fields in my class, one of a reference type and one of a primitive type. In the class' constructor, I try to initialize them to some custom values.

When I later query for those fields' values, they come back with Java's default values for them, `null` for the reference type and 0 for the primitive type. Why is this happening?

Here's a reproducible example:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringArray array = new StringArray();
        System.out.println(array.getCapacity()); // prints 0
        System.out.println(array.getElements()); // prints null
    }
}

class StringArray {
    private String[] elements;
    private int capacity;
    public StringArray() {
        int capacity = 10;
        String[] elements;
        elements = new String[capacity];
    }
    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }
    public String[] getElements() {
        return elements;
    }
}
```

I expected `getCapacity()` to return the value 10 and `getElements()` to return a properly initialized array instance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Entities (packages, types, methods, variables, etc.) defined in a Java program have [names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2). These are used to refer to those entities in other parts of a program.

The Java language defines a [*scope*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) for each name

> The *scope* of a declaration is the region of the program within which
>   the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a
>   simple name, provided it is visible (§6.4.1).

In other words, *scope* is a compile time concept that determines where a name can be used to refer to some program entity.

The program you've posted has multiple declarations. Let's start with

```
private String[] elements;
private int capacity;
```

These are [field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3) declarations, also called [*instance variables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1), ie. a type of member declared in a [class body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6). The Java Language Specification states

> The scope of a declaration of a member `m` declared in or inherited by a
>   class type `C` (§8.1.6) is the entire body of `C`, including any nested
>   type declarations.

This means you can use the names `elements` and `capacity` within the body of `StringArray` to refer to those fields.

The two first statements in your constructor body

```
public StringArray() {
    int capacity = 10;
    String[] elements;
    elements = new String[capacity];
}
```

are actually [local variable declaration statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)

> A *local variable* declaration statement declares one or more local variable names.

Those two statements introduce two new names in your program. It just so happens that those names are the same as your fields'. In your example, the local variable declaration for `capacity` also contains an initializer which **initializes that local variable**, not the field of the same name. Your field named `capacity` is initialized to the [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for its type, ie. the value `0`.

The case for `elements` is a little different. The local variable declaration statement introduces a new name, but what about the [assignment expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)?

```
elements = new String[capacity];
```

What entity is `elements` referring to?

The rules of *scope* state

> The scope of a *local variable* declaration in a block (§14.4) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer and including any further declarators to the right in
>   the local variable declaration statement.

The block, in this case, is the constructor body. But the constructor body is part of the body of `StringArray`, which means field names are also in scope. So how does Java determine what you're referring to?

Java introduces the concept of [*Shadowing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) to disambiguate.

> Some declarations may be shadowed in part of their scope by another
>   declaration of the same name, in which case a simple name cannot be
>   used to refer to the declared entity.

(a *simple name* being a single identifier, eg. `elements`.)

The documentation also states

> A declaration `d` of a **local variable** or exception parameter named `n`
>   **shadows**, throughout the scope of `d`, (a) **the declarations of any other
>   fields named `n` that are in scope at the point where `d` occurs**, and (b)
>   the declarations of any other variables named `n` that are in scope at
>   the point where `d` occurs but are not declared in the innermost class
>   in which `d` is declared.

This means that the local variable named `elements` takes priority over the field named `elements`. The expression

```
elements = new String[capacity];
```

is therefore initializing the local variable, not the field. The field is initialized to the [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) for its type, ie. the value `null`.

Inside your methods `getCapacity` and `getElements`, the names you use in the in their respective `return` statements refer to the fields since their declarations are the only ones in scope at that particular point in the program. Since the fields were initialized to `0` and `null`, those are the values returned.

The solution is to get rid of the local variable declarations altogether and therefore have the names refer to the instance variables, as you originally wanted. For example

```
public StringArray() {
    capacity = 10;
    elements = new String[capacity];
}
```

---

### Shadowing with constructor parameters

Similar to the situation described above, you may have [formal (constructor or method) parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) shadowing fields with the same name. For example

```
public StringArray(int capacity) {
    capacity = 10; 
}
```

*Shadowing* rules state

> A declaration `d` of a field or formal parameter named `n` shadows,
>   throughout the scope of `d`, the declarations of any other variables
>   named `n` that are in scope at the point where `d` occurs.

In the example above, the declaration of the constructor parameter `capacity` shadows the declaration of the instance variable also named `capacity`. It's therefore impossible to refer to the instance variable with its simple name. In such cases, we need to refer to it with its [qualified name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2).

> A qualified name consists of a name, a "." token, and an identifier.

In this case, we can use the [primary expression `this`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) as part of a [field access expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.1) to refer to the instance variable. For example

```
public StringArray(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = 10; // to initialize the field with the value 10
    // or
    this.capacity = capacity; // to initialize the field with the value of the constructor argument
}
```

There are *Shadowing* rules for every [kind of variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3), method, and type.

My recommendation is that you use unique names wherever possible so as to avoid the behavior altogether.

Answer (score 4):

`int capacity = 10;` in your constructor is declaring an local variable `capacity` which *shadows* the field of the class.

The remedy is to drop the `int`:

`capacity = 10;`

This will change the field value. Ditto for the other field in the class.

Didn't your IDE warn you of this shadowing?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't seem to. Does IntelliJ or whatever you're using do?

Comment: It's very common to shadow a class variable with a setter or constructor parameter. I would be surprised if an IDE would warn you about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to using variables in java/c/c++.  One is to declare the variable and the other is to use  the variable (whether assigning a value or using it in a calculation).

When you declare a variable you must declare its type.  So you would use

```
int x;   // to declare the variable
x = 7;   // to set its value
```

You do not have to re-declare a variable when using it:

```
int x;
int x = 7;
```

if the variable is in the same scope you will get a compiler error; however, as you are finding out, if the variable is in a different scope you will mask the first declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Another widely accepted convention is to have some prefix (or suffix - whatever you prefer) added to class members to distinguish them from local variables.

For example class members with `m_` prefix:

```
class StringArray {
  private String[] m_elements;
  private int      m_capacity;

  public StringArray(int capacity) {
    m_capacity = capacity;
    m_elements = new String[capacity];
  }

  public int getCapacity() {
    return m_capacity;
  }

  public String[] getElements() {
    return m_elements;
  }
}
```

Most IDEs have already available support for this notation, below is for Eclipse

[image]